# How do I get from Toronto to Boston in less than 12 hours?

Tags: budget, transportation, toronto, boston

I'm looking to get from Toronto to Boston in less than 12 hours.  Is the cheapest way to get from Toronto to Boston in that case to fly?  What other options are there that take under 12 hours of travel while being cheaper than flying?  E.g. bus, train, renting a car, etc.

I explicitly exclude any form of travel that is self-propelled, requires riding livestock in any form, or that violates any law of physics or thermodynamics.  Magic is fine.

Comment: Your definition of reasonable will need some clarification. Some people think it is perfectly reasonable to do things (for example cross the Sahara dessert on a bicycle) that other people will discard as impossible.

Comment: If you're truly confused, you can use the list already in the question as a starting point - bus, train, renting a car, and those modes of travel with a similar profile.  I will explicitly exclude riding a llama.

Comment: seeing your question has now collected 2 votes for closing and no answers, I think you should reconsider your comment and elaborate on the question.

Comment: @dlanod *I will explicitly exclude riding a llama.* Then explicitly say that.  Explicitly say what options you would consider.  Because biking from Toronto to Boston is also possible.

Comment: @Karlson In 12 hours?  It's ~900 km by road, meaning you'd need to average 75 km/h, which would be bit tough even if you're a doped-up Lance Armstrong.

Comment: @jpatokal His comment was before I added the 12 hour requirement, because apparently "reasonable" needs to be defined to more than the usual "something that your average joe would not attempt" definition.

Comment: Google Maps says you can drive in 9h 33m (I love the by-the-minute precision on long trips).  I've never spent more than half an hour at the border, but if you're brining in llamas or something you may need more time. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no direct buses available from Toronto to Boston on any of the major carriers [Greyhound](http://www.greyhound.com), [Coach](http://www.coachusa.com).  Rail is also out which will put you based on my estimation of [Amtrak](http://www.amtrak.com) service into about 17 hour range with transfer in New York Penn Station.

So your only option left would be to do a car rental, which may be just as expensive as the flight.  Plus border crossing could add enough time to your 9h 30min journey that it will put you over your time limit.

It is also possible that there are small bus companies or tour companies that offer the service but I can't find anything online.

Answer (score 9):

[Porter Airlines](https://www.flyporter.com/Flight/Tickets?culture=en-CA) offers flights from Toronto's City Center Airport to Boston which are not available through big travel agencies like Expedia. Their convenient city center airport can save taxi fare to the airport. Yes, this does involve flying.